# Hyperbolic paraboloid property

Tags: calculus, geometry

Let $z = f(x,y)$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $f(x,y)$ is a polynomial with $\deg f \geq 2$ with a property: through any point $P \in z$ we can draw two straight lines which are entirely in $z$. Prove that this surface is a hyperbolic paraboloid.

Can anyone help?